# Prometheus returned error "server returned HTTP status 401 Unauthorized" for .NET core api

Tags: api, .net-core, prometheus, prometheus-net

I have a .NET core api hosted in IIS which uses windows authentication. I'm using Prometheus to scrape metrics from this API. But I'm getting the error "server returned HTTP status 401 Unauthorized" for the api target. Can some help me how to configure prometheus for targets with Windows authentication?

When I tried to browse the metrics path separately, the browser is requesting for credentials and I'm able to view the metrics with my Windows authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, Prometheus seems to support basic (user/password) and OAuth bearer token authentication only. If your API/IIS doesn't support any of those, then you either need to disable authentication for the `/metrics` path or maybe set up a proxy that only allows `/metrics` requests and does the authentication for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I resolved the issue by enabling the Anonymous Authentication in API and IIS.